# Hosting an ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, ftp, host

I made a project in Visual Studio 2017 ( ASP.NET - Empty Web Site (C#) ) and then I tried to host it to internet, but I have no idea how.I have a free hosting ftp server and I get a free domain from (ro.000webhost.com). I made it just for learning.I tried to publish the project directly from Visual Studio and I chose Publish Method: FTP, I wrote the server name, user name and password. I pressed Validate Connection and it was ok and I clicked publish.
At Site Path, first time I wrote nothing, and the second time I wrote /public_html/ because apparently everything that is outside of this directory is forbidden.
When I publish the project in /publish_html/ and start the site on a browser, it appears that I do not have an index.php or index.html file, and if I click on Default.aspx, the browser shows me the code.
[image]
[image]
I gave up publishing directly from the visual studio, and I chose Publish Method: File System and I put my hand on FileZilla to try to upload the website manually, but I have the same problems.
Before I tried and worked with ftp servers, but with html, css, php files and so on and I had no problem. I searched and watched many tutorials on the internet, I read something from microsoft, but I did not understand so much. Can anyone help me with this? I'm a beginner in ASP.NET!
[image]

Comment: Your host does not support ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

The hosting service you are using is PHP hosting. It means that you cannot host an asp.net website using this server. However premium accounts have asp.net hosting feature. checkout this link for more information.

https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/asp-supported-by-server/13848

Comment: Oh, I see.Can you recommand me a free hosting site that supports ASP.NET?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Azure. 

Azure offers:

$200 credit - to explore services for 30 days 
12 months of popular free services
Always free - 25+ services

Comment: For that you require credit or debit card. However after 12months you either need to pay or terminate it